# Update score in real time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to create an app that will have real time update. It's kind of like a game. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Players will be playing, and as soon as someone gets the highest score, (while he's playing,) it should show it on all devices, and the score should be constantly changing as the high score user is playing.

I'm basically trying to get a leaderboard like [agars game](http://agar.io/), where the names are constantly changing.

I came across [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

How would I take care of adding new data?

[image]

Should I add a new one in xcode for every new highscore, or should I add a bunch manually, in the browser, then just replace their values for the highscore?

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

If you take a Look at the FireBase SwiftChat Demo you can fand a perfect explanation with code how to observe FireBase Events

Here is the needed Class

https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example/blob/master/FireChat-Swift/MessagesViewController.swift

Here is the part you need to view, its a copy of the class above

```
func setupFirebase() {
        // *** STEP 2: SETUP FIREBASE
        messagesRef = Firebase(url: "https://swift-chat.firebaseio.com/messages")

        // *** STEP 4: RECEIVE MESSAGES FROM FIREBASE (limited to latest 25 messages)
        messagesRef.queryLimitedToNumberOfChildren(25).observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            let text = snapshot.value["text"] as? String
            let sender = snapshot.value["sender"] as? String
            let imageUrl = snapshot.value["imageUrl"] as? String

            let message = Message(text: text, sender: sender, imageUrl: imageUrl)
            self.messages.append(message)
            self.finishReceivingMessage()
        })
    }

    func sendMessage(text: String!, sender: String!) {
        // *** STEP 3: ADD A MESSAGE TO FIREBASE
        messagesRef.childByAutoId().setValue([
            "text":text,
            "sender":sender,
            "imageUrl":senderImageUrl
        ])
    }
```

Here the whole project

https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not exactly sure what's going on the code. Can you please explain what going on? Thanks!

Comment: Dude are you sure you want to write a game if you don't understand what is going on in the code above?!? :-) Because it is already commented by Firebase? And they have a complete documentation on their website?!?

Comment: My bad! I didn't check the documentation! I have another problem I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214918/firebase-is-not-adding-all-the-data