# Firebase is not adding all the data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to add 25 values in my `firebase` scheme. I tried doing a simple `for loop` (in `ios` using `swift`) like this:

```
var firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "myUrl")

for var index = 0; index < 26; ++index {
    firebaseRef.setValue(["myValue\(index)" : 00])
}
```

But this is what happens: All the values are there for a second, then they all delete itself besides for the last one, which is `myValue25`. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

**Update**

Thanks to @Frank van Puffelen for putting me in the right direction!

I tried the following:

```
for var index = 1; index < 26; ++index {
        let dict = ["FullName" : "\(index)"]
        firebaseRef.childByAppendingPath("\(index)").setValue(dict)
}
```

All the data gets uploaded, but it's out of order. What can I do to fix that?

Here's the order that it goes to:

[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `ref.setValue(["myValue\(index)" : 00])`?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but I expect that you'll need to either call `firebaseRef.childByAppendingPath(@"\(index)", index).setValue(...)` or `firebaseRef.childByAutoId().setValue(...)`. Either way, please read this page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html, which teaches basic Firebase write operations.

Comment: counting from zero to 25 leads to 26 lines. Usually I wouldnt mention it, but "besides for the last one" makes me wonder.

Comment: @der_michael I fixed it

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks! I read it before, but I guess I didn't catch on that you have to put in the path! I update the question